# I want to select just string before comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select whole word until a comma comes. If a comma is there in paragraph this should be not shown. Also, if I select text half it should show the complete word.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#content > div.row > div > p:nth-child(10)").click(function() {
    var s = window.getSelection();
    s.modify('extend', 'backward', 'word');
    var b = s.toString();

    s.modify('extend', 'forward', 'word');
    var a = s.toString();
    s.modify('move', 'forward', 'character');
    $(".location-selected").remove();
    $("#content > h2").append('<div class="location-selected">you have selected 
      location '+(b+a)+' < /div>');
    });
  });
```

Here is my line:

```
Gqaka, Gqaqala, Gqiba, Gqobonco, Gqogqora, Gqola, Gqoloma, Gqora, Gqubeni, Gqubonco, Gqukangqa, Gquk
```

If I click on `Gqiba` it should show just this word. If I drag with mouse selection `Gqiba, Gqobonco` it should get just one word before comma. This means it should get `Gqiba` - it should ignore `Gqobonco`. Also if I select `iba` from mouse selection it should show full word which is `Gqiba` it should not select just `iba` and show. Kindly help me.

Comment: `split` the string and get the values by even keys.

Comment: Would you mind to improve your spelling and punctation? You can you doing it by click the edit link underneath your question. Thanks.

Comment: its working ok but when i select more than one word it should not select more than one it should select just first complete word before comma and if i select half of first word it should select complete that word also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to put all your comma separated words into span tags, there is no other way to do so.

```js
var listPara = "Gqaka, Gqaqala, Gqiba, Gqobonco, Gqogqora, Gqola, Gqoloma, Gqora, Gqubeni, Gqubonco, Gqukangqa, Gquk";

var listItems = listPara.split(",");

listItems.forEach(function(item) {
    $("#selectHolder").append("<span>"+ item + "</span>, ");
});

$("#selectHolder").on('click', 'span', function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="selectHolder"></p>
```

Or you can use this bootstrap plugin:
http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/

Comment: Thanks it solve my problem but i have large number of countries in <p> tag Gqaka, Gqaqala, Gqiba, Gqukangqa, Gqaqala sdf, Gqaqala-ds, Gqaqala it's about 12000 so i want all in seperate also i want them in dropdown how i can do that? so when i click on some one it should take value of that element

Comment: var listPara = "Gqaka, Gqaqala, Gqiba, Gqobonco, Gqogqora, Gqola, Gqoloma, Gqora, Gqubeni, Gqubonco, Gqukangqa, Gquk";

var listItems = listPara.split(",");

listItems.forEach(function(item) {

$("#content > div:nth-child(2) > div > p:nth-child(2)").append('<div><select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" tabindex="2"><option value='+ item+'">'+ item + '</option></div>');

});

Comment: how i can add this list in one dropdown it showing me a lot of dropdowns

Comment: i want to add all countries in one dropdown 


var listPara = "Gqaka, Gqaqala, Gqiba, Gqobonco, Gqogqora, Gqola, Gqoloma, Gqora, Gqubeni, Gqubonco, Gqukangqa, Gquk";

var listItems = listPara.split(",");

listItems.forEach(function(item) {
var opt='<option value='+ item+'">'+ item + '</option>';
console.log(opt);
});

$("#content > div:nth-child(2) > div > p:nth-child(2)").append('<div><select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" tabindex="2">opt</div>');